# Rows to Columns (crosstab) with many rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, jet

The third-party application I'm working with (this is NOT Access, but uses the MDAC library) has three Access tables structured like this:

**TagTable**

```
TagName TagIndex TagType  
peach   0        Float  
apple   1        Float  
grape   2        Float  
cherry  3        String
```

and so on for many more rows

**FloatTable**

```
DateAndTime         TagIndex Value
03/02/2012 14:03:03 0        123.456
03/02/2012 14:03:03 1        123.456
03/02/2012 14:03:03 2        123.456
03/02/2012 14:06:05 0        456.789
03/02/2012 14:06:05 1        456.789
03/02/2012 14:06:05 2        456.789
```

And so on for many more rows and times

**StringTable**

```
DateAndTime         TagIndex Value
03/02/2012 14:03:03 3        'Some string...'
03/02/2012 14:06:05 3        'Some other string'
```

And so on for many more rows and times

What I want to do is execute a query or run code (VBA) to get to a recordset like this:

```
DateAndTime         peach   apple   grape   cherry
03/02/2012 14:03:03 123.456 123.456 123.456 'Some string...'
03/02/2012 14:06:05 456.789 456.789 456.789 'Some other string'
```

And so on.

Normally, I would do this with "self join"s or unions no problem. The problem is that there will be at least 90+ rows in the TagTable so 90+ columns in the result.  I can't see doing 90+ joins in a query, even if Access could do that.  I CAN run some VBA code within the application, if needed.  I looked into using use TRANSFORM...PIVOT, but there is no aggregation going on. I looked at a "crosstab" query also, but this will get complicated with 90+ rows/columns.  I know I can do this with VBA, but I was hoping that there is some Jet SQL magic that I can use that will help.

Comment: Have you tried creating the crosstab using the query design window? It does not look that complicated to me. Do not forget that you can use a join between two crosstabs, furthermore, if this is a once off, you can also use a crosstab to create a new table.

Comment: @Remou: I hadn't tried the design window, so I tried just now.  Access is wanting some sort of aggregate function, which I don't want here.  The research I've been doing on crosstab queries looks like they all want some sort of aggregate function.  Is this true?  If so, then I can't use a crosstab.

Comment: There are ways round. If the intersection of peach and time is just one value, that is, there are not multiple records for peach with the same time, you can use First(Value), Min(Value) or Max(Value) to return the correct result. This is the aggregate function that MS Access is looking for.

Comment: Woot!  That's the answer.  That was the piece I was missing - Thanks! @Remou: How do I give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you wish to use a crosstab to denormalize data. If the intersection of peach and time is just one value, that is, there are not multiple records for peach with the same time, you can use First(Value), Min(Value) or Max(Value) to return the correct result. This is the aggregate function that MS Access is looking for.